# Unity OnTriggerEnter2d() Not working | Trying to switch between Scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm pretty new to unity and I've been trying to get this scene switch to work however the trigger doesn't seem to be activating when the player hits it.  The debug.Log is doing nothing so I'm stumped.  I know my terminology may make no sense so let me show some pictures.  If youre able to help it would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

This is the inspector panel for the object I want to trigger

[image]

This is the inspector the player

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneChangeScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int iLevelToLoad;
    public string sLevelToLoad;

    public bool useIntegerToLoadLevel = false;

    void start()
    {

    }

    void update()
    {

    }



    private void onTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
        Debug.Log("Somethings Being Triggered!");
        LoadScene();
        }
    }

    void LoadScene()
    {
        if(useIntegerToLoadLevel)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(iLevelToLoad);
        }
        else
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sLevelToLoad);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try putting the debug.log outside of the condition to see if it's even entering the method? Or even better.. just put a break point on the if statement and run in debug mode? Also C# is case sensitive. `onTriggerEnter2D` is not the same as `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Likely unity is not even hitting that method to start with.. I see you did the same with `start` and `update`

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari Thank you so much, I've been rustling with this issue for about a day at this point.  I need to make sure I'm paying more attention to cases.

Comment: Visual studio has some auto complete features you should accustom yourself to use it. Besides it's a C# convention to start methods with uppercase. I would invest some time learning the VS shortcuts. Speeds up workflow alot..

Comment: definitely will do, again thank you for the speedy response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity [Monobehavior Lifecycle methods](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) start with a capital and C# methods are case-sensitive. Therefore, the following methods need to be corrected to be used by Unity:

- `start` => `Start`
- `update` => `Update`
- `onTriggerEnter2D` => `OnTriggerEnter2D`

Since the C# convention is that methods start with uppercase you'll less likely encounter this issue if you assume it starts with an uppercase letter rather than lower case. But it is better to confirm! Also if you are using Visual Studio, you can avoid much of these pains by investing the time to learn some shortcuts.

Comment: It is a convention yes but in this case this wouldn't matter. It rather needs to be upper case because Unity's messaging system which is invoking these methods is looking for them with that exact name ;)

Comment: The point of the convention is a hint that "If you use uppercases you'll likely not encounter this issue often, since it is the convention" but I'll make it more explicit.

Answer (score -2):

Hey I just spotted that you initiated the `bool` `useIntegerToLoadLevel` to be `false` and you are using this condition to load the scene in the `if` statement and the `bool` is never being set to `true`.

Try setting this `bool` to `true` when you enter the trigger, that is in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method, should definitely work. It is a minor bug that anyone can make.

Comment: yea but he has an else branch where he loads a scene; so that is not really an issue.